# How should icons be imported and used in a large React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, icons

I have a React application that makes use of a lot of React icons. I've thought of different ways to import and use them but I'm not really sure if there are any major impacts to performance that should be considered.



**1. Import all my icons in my top level `App` component and pass them down to each component as needed.**

*This is what I'm doing now, thinking I'm only ever importing the SVGs once, but it's becoming annoying passing these icons down through higher order and child components.*

```
import { ReactComponent as IconApartment } from './icons/material/apartment.svg';
import { ReactComponent as IconBookmark } from './icons/material/bookmark.svg';
import { ReactComponent as IconCalendarToday } from './icons/material/calendar-today.svg';
// etc.

const icons = {
  apartment: <IconApartment />,
  bookmark: <IconBookmark />,
  calendar: <IconCalendar />,
};

return (
  <MyComponent icons={icons} />
):
```

**2. I could just import icons in each component that needs them.**

*This makes sense but I'm worried that a lot of components use the same icon, and repeating the same import for each seems counter productive.*

**MyComponent**

```
import { ReactComponent as IconApartment } from './icons/material/apartment.svg';

return (
  <div>{<IconApartment />}</div>
);
```

**MyOtherComponent**

```
import { ReactComponent as IconApartment } from './icons/material/apartment.svg';

return (
  <div>{<IconApartment />}</div>
);
```

**3. I could make a custom hook.**

*It would essentially do option 1 but rather than being passed as a prop to child components, I could instantiate it independently.*

**Custom Hook**

```
import { ReactComponent as IconApartment } from './icons/material/apartment.svg';
import { ReactComponent as IconBookmark } from './icons/material/bookmark.svg';
import { ReactComponent as IconCalendarToday } from './icons/material/calendar-today.svg';
// etc.

export function useIcons() {

  const icons = {
    apartment: <IconApartment />,
    bookmark: <IconBookmark />,
    calendar: <IconCalendar />,
  };

  return icons;
}
```

**MyComponent**

```
import { useIcons } from './hooks.js';

const { icons } = useIcons();

return (
  <div>{icons.apartment}</div>
);
```

--

What is the most performant solution? What is the best practice?

Comment: This is mainly a religious argument. Personally, I prefer staying away from potentially creating dependency chains, which is less scalable due to the unnecessary complexity it adds. This is an inherent problem with propagating props from the top level. I prefer requiring the module in each component that will use it, for two reasons. 1) it's impossible to mess up the dependency chain when rearranging the component hierarchy, and 2) it's extremely simple and easy to add to components that require it.

Comment: That's basically how I feel, which is option 2. It's inline with how we import and use other JS modules. I think I'm just getting caught up in prop drilling and how React is used. It just feels dirty dismissing the DRY principle. However, I could be persuaded for one or the other if there were perf benefits, which is what I'm hoping to learn.

Comment: Yes. And there are not noticeable performance differences when using either method. It's up to you!